# Haskell - Double guard expression = "parse error on input `|'"?

Tags: haskell

I am currently working on some algorithms for binary trees. However, I came around a problem I cannot quite solve. I always get following error:

> error: parse error on input ‘|’

While I understand that this has to do with spacing, I think I should have done it correctly.

```
delTree a Leaf = error "No tree here!"
delTree a (Branch left w right)
          | a < w = delTree a left
          | a > w = delTree a right
          | a == w 
                      | ...
```

Am I missing something? Does it have to do with using the guard expression twice?

Edit: 
This is my data structure

```
data BinTree a = Leaf | Branch (BinTree a) a (BinTree a) deriving Show
```

With delTree I am trying to delete a node in a binary tree. The only way I see is by of course looking for the proper value and then replacing it with the left or right child (depends on if there is a left child). If there is another way then doing it with nested guards I am open for advice!

Comment: Well, obviously this is _not_ correct Haskell with those `...` there. You seem to be trying to write nested guards. Haskell doesn't support that (not sure why, actually), but if you show the full code we can prompt you to some alternative. In this case, there's probably no reason to nest anything at all – the `a==w` check is redundant anyway, so just continue any further checks on the same level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited my initial post. `...`I have just written because I wasnt quite sure on how to proceed yet-.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Probably, guards can't be nested because they do not require indentation, making e.g. `x | c1 | c2 = 1 | c3 = 2` ambiguous (is `c3` under `c1`? or is that at the top level?). Of course, this observation only moves the question to "why don't they require indentation?".

Comment: If you want nested guards, you might be looking to conjoin some of the statements, e.g `| a == w && exp1 | a==w && exp2`. But like lefaroundabout said in his first comment, the `a==w` is redundant if the first two guards have been passed. So just use `| exp1 | exp2`

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the `MultiWayIf` extension.  Unfortunately, there's a shift in syntax from `=` to `->` that's a little jarring:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

delTree a Leaf = error "No tree here!"
delTree a (Branch left w right)
          | a < w = delTree a left
          | a > w = delTree a right
          | a == w
            = if | False -> error "whatever"
                 | True  -> error "something else"
```

but you could switch your outer guards to a multi-way "if" for a consistent look:

```
delTree a Leaf = error "No tree here!"
delTree a (Branch left w right)
  = if | a < w  -> delTree a left
       | a > w  -> delTree a right
       | a == w -> if | False -> error "whatever"
                      | True  -> error "something else"
```

Alternatively, consider a `where` helper before getting too fancy:

```
delTree a Leaf = error "No tree here!"
delTree a (Branch left w right)
          | a < w = delTree a left
          | a > w = delTree a right
          | a == w = found
  where found | False = error "whatever"
              | True  = error "something else"
```

Comment: I think it's important to note that, following this approach, should the nested guards be all false, the next outer guard will not be considered. This is a problem only when 1) there is a next outer guard to try, and 2) the inner guards are non-exhaustive.

Comment: Interesting point.  I guess I assumed the intended semantics of nested guards would be like the multiway-if version, but the alternative you suggest is maybe the more natural one.

Answer (score 0):

A little repetition is not always a bad thing.

```
delTree a (Branch left w right)
          | a < w = delTree a left
          | a > w = delTree a right
delTree a (Branch left w right) | ...
                                | ...
```

If neither `a < w` nor `a > w` is true, you can assume that `a == w` must be true, and it can be left implied in the second definition. You might even go so far as to use *three* definitions, some with only a single guard.

```
delTree a (Branch left w _) | a < w = delTree a left
delTree a (Branch _ w right) | a > w = delTree a right
delTree a (Branch left w right) | ...
```

You might also consider using `compare` rather than the comparison operators.

```
delTree a (Branch left w right) = case compare a w of
                                     LT -> delTree a left
                                     GT -> delTree a right
                                     EQ -> ...
```

Comment: Does using compare have any benefits I am not aware of?

Comment: Aside from allowing you to reduce the three branches to a single syntactic construct, none that I am aware of.